# R Downloading Pictures from URL

Tags: r, download

I have a problem downloading pictures from websites with R.
It seems like the image is properly recognized by `download.file`:

trying URL 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xh9kO.png'
Content type 'image/png' length 16592 bytes (16 Kb)
opened URL
downloaded 16 Kb

And it also is downloaded with the right name and file ending (.png) to the right directory.

```
download.file("https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xh9kO.png",paste(**yourDEST**,"Stackoverflow",".png",sep=""))
```

however, the file is butchered and can't be opened.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: This fixed my problem :) thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I couldn't find a duplicate, so I'll just answer.

The `download.file` help is a bit fragmented on this, but if you read it all carefully you can find that, on Windows, the default `mode = "w"` is only suitable for text files. For binary files (pretty much everything but text) you need `mode = "wb"`. This will be done automagically *if* the URL ends in any of `gz, .bz2, .xz, .tgz, .zip, .rda` or `.RData`, however for anything else you need to specify `mode = "wb"` yourself.

Answer (score 3):

You can also switch to the `httr` package:

```
library(httr)

GET("http://i.imgur.com/pszAeGh.png", 
    write_disk(paste("/tmp/", "Stackoverflow", ".png", sep="")))
```

A plus of `write_disk` is that it won't overwrite by default (i.e. you get implicit caching) and no special treatment is required vis-a-vis binary vs text.